# How to hide and show in my case using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

I am  new to jQuery. I have a **index.html** page,

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
</body>
```

I would like the feature that when page loaded, "content" area shows a list:

```
<div id="my-list">
    <select id="carlist" size="10">
          <option>BMW</option>
          <option>TOYOTA</option>
          <option>SKODA</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

when user select a car from the list option, the list "`my-list`" disappear(**hide**), and an image will be **shown** in the "`content`" area.

That's hide the selection filed and show the image in the same "`content`" area.

How to do that in jQuery?

I tried:

```
var mylist=$('#my-list');
mylist.change(function(){
    mylist.hide()
    SOMEIMAGE.show()
}
```

But, where to define "`my-list`" and the `image` are in the same "`content`" area? How to implement this all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var mylist=$('#carlist');
mylist.change(function(){
    mylist.hide();
    var container = mylist.parent();
    container.find('img').remove();
    container.append('<img src="x.jpg" />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = $('#my-list');
mylist.change(function(){
    mylist.hide();
    container = $('#content');
    container.html('<img ... />');
)};
```

There are a number of ways, though, to show new content, with [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) for example, in case you don't want to overwrite all the html code inside `<div id="content" />`, or using the functions [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) if the `<img />` is already there.
Also you will have to have in consideration knowing **which option was selected** inside the `change()`function and act accordingly.